# Angular Version 9.1.4 import error, error TS2314:

Tags: angular

I've built an angular lib using angular version 9.0.7,

```
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core         9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.7
@schematics/angular          9.0.7
@schematics/update           0.900.7
rxjs                         6.5.3
```

This was built and imported with no errors, by applications using the same version, but when I try to import this lib to an angular 9.14.7, I got this error TS2314.

static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef

I suspect that this error is related with ivy.
When i create a lib using angular version 9.14.7, it runs and import without problems.

I already tried to uninstall all node_modules and install again, but the error persists.
anyone are facing the same issue on this version of angular?

OBS: when I compiled the lib on angular 9.0.7, I've got this warning

It is not recommended to publish Ivy libraries to NPM repositories.

Comment: did you use cli to generate your project.?

Comment: yes, I always use CLI to generate default projects

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're using:

```
ng build <library> --prod
```

Comment: no, i'm not using --prod flag, because it's still in development, library and application, so we're testing the implementation of both

Comment: Is the library linked?

Comment: I have had issues with Ivy, so I make sure to use `ng build <library> --prod`

Comment: yes, what's weird, it's seems to recompile when i'm importing, it's related to ivy

Comment: i will run with --prod flag, and relate if  it's work, but it's hard to pin point what cause the error and why